# Aborting synchronous ReadDirectoryChangesW

Tags: winapi

I'm using the synchrounous flavor of `ReadDirectoryChangesW` in a thread. Everything works perfectly well.

But I'm unable to terminate the thread otherwise than calling `TerminateThread` from my main thread, because if there is no activity in the monitored directory, `ReadDirectoryChangesW` is waiting forever.

The solution with `TerminateThread` works, but this is kind of dirty.

Another solution would be to create a dummy file in the monitored directory which will unblock `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, but this is just another hack.

So is there a way to unblock/abort `ReadDirectoryChangesW` properly ?

Comment: Is `CancelSynchronousIo(your_thread_handle)` not working?

Comment: I didn't check, because my application is required to run on Windows XP and CancelSynchronousIo is only available on Vista ord later.

Comment: Unluckily that's true for `CancelIoEx` as well... might worth trying `NtCancelIoFile` with a handle to the directory if undocumented stuff is acceptable for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch to using it with a completion routine and immediately after the call to `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` call a wait function which puts you into an alertable wait state and also waits on an event which you use to abort the wait...

Answer (score 1):

If you open the handle with FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT then it is possible to use the undocumented NtAlertThread to send a signal to stop the wait.